# How to improve the performance of a REST call which internally other REST calls

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, caching, pagination

I am creating an endpoint which retrieves me some data and in this call it calls 3 different REST calls and due to this it hampers the performance of my application.

```
My Endpoint Code:

 1. REST call to get the userApps()
 2. iterate over userAPPs
    2.1 make REST call to get the appDetails
    2.2 make use of above response to call the 3rd REST call which returns list.
    2.3 iterate over the above list and filter out the required fields and put it in main response object.
 3.return response
```

So, this much complexity hampers the performance.

I have tried to add the multithreading concept but the time taken by normal code and multi threading is almost same.

Condition is like, We can not modify the 3 external REST calls to support the pagination.

We can not add the pagination because we don't have any database. 
Is there any solution?

Comment: Are you using spring boot?

Comment: Since the calls are dependent on the result of prev. call, we cannot make the calls async. You could reduce rest time by using RPC calls. They are supported inside micro service architechture as well.

Comment: @Naveen yes I am using Spring boot

Comment: @AdityaGupta I haven't used the RPC before but will it support or will reduce the the time for like 100 iterations?

Comment: RPC reduces the network turnaround time( or whatever the term is for the reply to come back to caller), hence individual calls will be faster. Thats, what we can do here.

Comment: Spring boot has an annotation @Async please go through it once

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't *add* threading, you should *remove* threads altogether. I.e. you should make all your code non-blocking. This just means that all the work will basically be done in the http-client's threadpool, and all the waiting can be done in the operating system's selector (which we want).

Here is some code how this core logic would work, assuming your http calls return `CompletableFuture`.

```java
public CompletableFuture<List<Something>> retrieveSomethings() {
    return retrieveUserApps().thenCompose(this::retriveAllAppsSomethings);
}

public CompletableFuture<List<Something>> retrieveAllAppsSomethings(List<UserApp> apps) {
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(
        apps.stream().map(this::retriveAppSomethings).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new))
    .apply(listOfLists -> listOfLists.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .apply(this::filterSomethings);
}

public CompletableFuture<List<Something>> retreiveAppSomethings(UserApp app) {
    return retrieveAppDetails(app).thenCompose(this::retreiveAppDetailSomethings);
}
```

All this does, is to make everything non-blocking, so everything that *can* be run in parallel *will* run in parallel. There is no need to limit anything, since everything will be run in the http-client's threadpool, which is most likely limited. It doesn't matter anyway, because waiting will not take up a thread.

All you have to do for the above code is to implement `retrieveUserApps()`, `retrieveAppDetails(app)` and `retrieveAppDetailSometings(appDetail)`. All of which should return a `CompletableFuture<>` and be implemented with the async-enabled version of your http client.

This will make retrieving data for 1 app or 100 apps the same, since all of those will run in parallel (assuming they all take the same time and the downstream systems can handle this many parallel requests).